# How do I mount a volume by label in Alpine Linux?

Tags: mount, alpine-linux, volume-label

I'm running a Docker container based on Alpine (specifically the `balenalib/armv7hf-alpine` image). Within the container I want to mount a USB drive by its label, but the Alpine `mount` command doesn't appear to support the `--label` option.

I'm an Alpine newbie, but under Raspbian/Debian, I'd just use, e.g.:

```
mount --label USBDRIVE /mnt/usbdrive
```

Under Alpine I can successfully mount the drive, but I have to use its device name instead of its label, e.g.:

```
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/usbdrive
```

Is there an approach I can use to achieve mount by label under Alpine? E.g.: a different version of `mount`? Or a way of finding the volume name by iterating through the labels on all available volumes?

**Edit**: OK, here's a solution that works (with apologies for my Bash scripting):

```
VOLUME=$(for VOL in $(fdisk -l | grep ^/dev/sd | awk '{print $1}'); \
         do blkid $VOL; done | grep USBDRIVE | awk -F: '{print $1}')

mount $VOLUME /mnt/usbdrive
```

This lists all disks using `fdisk`, isolates all the `/dev/sd*` entries, uses `blkid` to find the volume labels, identifies the label required and grabs its volume name. (Exceptions ignored for ease of presentation).

Comment: Check if you have a LABEL in `/dev/disk/by-label/`

Comment: Thanks ... I'm not seeing any labels in the `/dev` directories. I have a basic solution now, however.

Comment: would be nice if you could post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are neater ways to do this, but -- as noted in the edit above -- the approach below works for my needs. Note that it would break if multiple volumes with the required label were present.

```
VOLUME=$(for VOL in $(fdisk -l | grep ^/dev/sd | awk '{print $1}'); \
     do blkid $VOL; done | grep USBDRIVE | awk -F: '{print $1}')

mount $VOLUME /mnt/usbdrive
```

Answer (score 1):

Or just use blkid's -L option:

```
mount $(blkid -L USBDRIVE) /mnt/usbdrive
```